# Asymptotic behaviour of Scala methods

Tags: scala, time-complexity

Is there somewhere I can find out the expected **time** and **space** complexities of operations on collections like HashSet, TreeSet, List and so on?

Is one just expected to know these from the properties of the abstract-data-types themselves?

I know of [Performance characteristics for Scala collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html), but this only mentions some very basic operations. Perhaps the rest of the operations for these collections are built purely from a small base-set, but then, it seems I am just expected to know that they have implemented them in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance characteristics of the other methods is really difficult to assert. Consider the following:

- These methods are all implemented based on `foreach` or `iterator`, and at usually very high levels in the hierachy. `Vector`'s `map` is implemented on `collection.TraversableLike`, for example.
  To add insult to injury, which method implementation is used depends on the linearization of the class inheritance. This also applies to any method called as a helper. It has happened before that changes here caused unforeseen performance problems.
  Since `foreach` and `iterator` are both `O(n)`, any improved performance depends on specialization at other methods, such as `size` and `slice`.
- For many of them, there's further dependency on the performance characteristics of the builder that was provided, which depends on the call site instead of the definition site.

So the result is that the place where the method is defined -- and documented -- does not have near enough information to state its performance characteristics, and may depend not only on how other methods are implemented by the inheriting collection, but even by the performance characteristics of an object, Builder, obtained from CanBuildFrom, that is passed at the *call site*.

At best, any such documentation would be described in terms of other methods. Which doesn't mean it isn't worthwhile, but it isn't easily done -- and hard tasks on open source projects depend on volunteers, who usually work at what they like, not what is needed.

Answer (score 8):

The guide for the other methods should be - just think what an efficient implementation should look like.

Most other bulk-operations on collections (operations that process each element in the collection) are `O(n)`, so they are not mentioned there. Examples are `filter`, `map`, `foreach`, `indexOf`, `reverse`, `find` ...

Methods returning iterators or streams like `combinations` and `permutations` are usually `O(1)`.

Methods involving 2 collections are usually `O(max(n, m))` or `O(min(n, m))`. These are `zip`, `zipAll`, `sameElements`, `corresponds`, ...

Methods `union`, `diff`, and `intersect` are `O(n + m)`.

Sort variants are, naturally, `O(nlogn)`. The `groupBy` is `O(nlogn)` in the current implementation. The `indexOfSlice` uses the KMP algorithm and is `O(m + n)`, where `m` and `n` are lengths of the strings.

Methods such as `+:`, `:+` or `patch` are generally `O(n)` as well, unless you are dealing with a specific case of an immutable collection for which the operation in question is more efficient - for example, prepending an element on a functional `List` or appending an element to a `Vector`.

Methods `toX` are generally `O(n)`, as they have to iterate all the elements and create a new collection. An exception is `toStream` which builds the collection lazily - so it's `O(1)`. Also, whenever `X` is the type of the collection `toX` just returns `this`, being `O(1)`.

Iterator implementations should have an `O(1)` (amortized) `next` and `hasNext` operations. Iterator creation should be worst-case `O(logn)`, but `O(1)` in most cases.

Comment: This seems a little odd, as if it is anything but a completely trivial data-structure, there could easily be some non-trivial better algorithm for some operations. For instance, intersection on TreeSets might not just be the same as checking each element of one set for membership in the other.

Comment: What may be of importance to note would be the iterator performance of collections with `eC` or `log(n)` access. This seems to be a bit optimised for `Vector` but I haven’t checked the other collections.

Comment: @MGwynne - I'm only referring to methods not already described in your link. Those described in the link have very specific and highlighted complexities. Wherever some general method can be implemented more efficiently in terms of those methods, this was usually done, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Debilski - I've added iterator creation and operations performance.

Comment: @axel22 I'm referring to "just think what an efficient implementation should be". The complexity of an efficient implementation (likely) isn't *always* trivial like those you mention. They might be implemented in a trivial way, but there might be some better way for some cases, and so I'm wondering if there's some reference which explicitly states these things, rather than having to assume they are implemented as they "should be".

Comment: @MGwynne - you're right, that comment is a bit vague. It's meant to be a general guideline to figure out the general worst-case complexity - but in some cases a particular data-structure may be more optimized. Examples of this that I can think of are vectors and list.

Comment: @axel22 Indeed, your answer is a nice reference though :).